# DOM Exception on filesystem url sharing via window messaging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-filesystem, arraybuffer

I have to share dynamic generated content file URL to the iframe. I am getting DOM Exception 12 while passing URL to iframe.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('vwr-frame').contentWindow;
iframe.postMessage({Url:url }); //URL is filesystem URL
```

do I need to specify bufferType or is it possible to send url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send `targetOrigin`, it is not an optional parameter. Passing `"*"` may be enough.

```
otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin);
//                                     ^
```

The [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) page for [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) has more information.

Comment: is targetOrigin is required field? where could I get more resources on window messaging? thankyou

Comment: You can read the [**WHATWG** page](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/web-messaging.html#web-messaging), but MDN (linked in answer) should be an easier read.